# Quartz setup failure in Azure App Service

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, quartz-scheduler

I have a Azure App service up and Running. Spring boot app is deployed. When I try to add Quartz scheduler setup in Spring boot app, it works fine in local. But when we move to Azure app, scheduler setup not booted with the below message.

Basically it looks for host name, in Azure App service can we find the host name? Any configuration required to resolve hostname?

```
2020-05-08 11:35:57.155 ERROR 123 --- [main] org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory      : Couldn't generate instance Id!
org.quartz.SchedulerException: Couldn't get host name!at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleInstanceIdGenerator.generateInstanceId(SimpleInstanceIdGenerator.java:36)at org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory.instantiate(StdSchedulerFactory.java:1247)at
```

Please Note:
Commenting the properties in Quartz will set default value but we need to go with Auto approach
org.quartz.scheduler.instanceId=AUTO

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if you can get the hostname of the app service your code is running on but could you use `spring.quartz.properties.org.quartz.scheduler.instanceIdGenerator.class=CustomInstanceIDGenerator.class` as outlined in [this blog post](https://medium.com/@ChamithKodikara/spring-boot-2-quartz-2-scheduler-integration-a8eaaf850805) where CustomInstnaceIDGenerator is

```java
public class CustomInsntanceIdGenerator implements InstanceIdGenerator {

    @Override
    public String generateInstanceId() throws SchedulerException {
        try {
            return UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        } catech (Exception ex) {
            throw new SchedulerException("Couldn't genereate UUID", ex);
        }
    }
}
```

This would allow you not be dependent on the hostname.

EDIT: Give this a shot

```java
private String getComputerName()
{
    Map<String, String> env = System.getenv();
    if (env.containsKey("COMPUTERNAME"))
        return env.get("COMPUTERNAME");
    else if (env.containsKey("HOSTNAME"))
        return env.get("HOSTNAME");
    else
        return "Unknown Computer";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This occur when you use `spring.quartz.properties.org.quartz.scheduler.instanceId=AUTO` application property. To overcome this you have to map `127.0.0.1 <machine ip>` in your host file if not it will throw  `java.net.UnknownHostException: ip-1x-xx-xx-2xx: Temporary failure in name resolution` or if you want to give some unique value from system property you have to change
`spring.quartz.properties.org.quartz.scheduler.instanceId=SYS_PROP` according to the doc.

> org.quartz.scheduler.instanceId
>
> Can be any string, but must be unique for all schedulers working as if
>   they are the same ‘logical’ Scheduler within a cluster. You may use
>   the value “AUTO” as the instanceId if you wish the Id to be generated
>   for you. Or the value “SYS_PROP” if you want the value to come from
>   the system property “org.quartz.scheduler.instanceId”.